# SQL: Need to replace same value in multiple columns

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that finds a single value in multiple columns and then update
those columns where that value exist.

The values that needs to be replaced are in columns that end with _m1

Example table:

```
o_id   a_m1   a_m2   b_m1   b_m2
1      bb     cc     bb     cc
2      cc     null   bb     cc
```

I need to find all of the "cc" values in columns that end with _m1 and then update those columns to 'bb"

Comment: @user1991499 - Do you really understand what you wrote yourself?

Comment: Do you know the columns which end in _m1 or do you need to get the table metadata to obtain those columns first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET a_m1=REPLACE(a_m1,'cc','bb'),
      b_m1=REPLACE(b_m1,'cc','bb')
```

OR

```
SELECT a_m1 = CASE WHEN a_m1='cc' THEN 'bb' ELSE a_m1 END,
       b_m1 = CASE WHEN b_m1='cc' THEN 'bb' ELSE b_m1 END
```

Note:

These do two different things -- I'm not sure what you want.

They both only modify a_m1 and b_m1.

In the first every place in the string where `cc` occurs is replaced with `bb`

In the second if the value equals exactly `cc` it is changed to `bb` otherwise no change.

Comment: I know the columns that end in _m1

Comment: @user1991499 - I've no idea what this comment means.  Was it a reply to Bogdan on his comment above.

Comment: It was in response to @user1991499 question of "Do you know the columns which end in _m1?"